# Timeout Exceptions

Tags: java

This is my below code, I am confuse why this thing is happening. In this code getLocationTimeout is a method in which I am passing two things- one is the ip address and second is the timeout in milliseconds. So I will get the timeout exception if the response is not getting back in under 5 milliseconds in this particular case. So when I ran this below code, I am getting few timeout exceptions for few ip address. That means some response is taking longer time (greater than 5 ms) but the most important thing that I am confuse about is if I am getting timeout exceptions (time taken to get the response is greater than 5 ms) then why the program is entering in that if loop in which I am having difference > 5. It should have thrown the timeout exception at previous place. What can be the possible reason for this? It is because of catch block? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
long runs = 10000;
long difference = 0;

while (runs > 0) {
    String ipAddress = generateIPAddress();
    long start_time = System.nanoTime();

    try {
        resp = GeoLocationService.getLocationTimeout(ipAddress, 5);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Timeout Exception");
    }

    long end_time = System.nanoTime();

    if (resp == null || (resp.getLocation() == null)) {
        difference  = 0;
    } else if (resp.getLocation() != null) {
        difference = (end_time - start_time) / 1000000;
    }

    if (difference> 5) {
        System.out.println("Debug");
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT NOT EXPECTED**
Ok. The problem that I am having is- It should print out **Timeout Exception** for any response greater than 5 milliseconds. But in some case what's happening is that it is printing Debug but without printing Timeout Exception and with the help of debugger I found that if the difference is around 6 or 8 then I saw pointer entering that if loop of debug.

Comment: OT, but 5ms is a ridiculously short timeout for any network operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for adding the info - thought I would put this as a different answer, as its a different tack.  So from the info you added I think it just looks like the extra time is just from the extra try catch etc instructions its running (I think).  However maybe you should look at redoing the code really.  The getLocationByIpTimeout call does all the timing you need I think, so then you can just do whatever logic you need in the catch block, i.e. you don't need all the timing stuff - will that do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then yes you are doing the call to getLocationByIpTimeout inside a try...catch block, so any exceptions thrown will be caught, dealt with (by logging to Sysout in your case, and then the program will continue into the if blocks - is that the problem you are seeing - what do you want to happen?

Comment: Are you seeing this after several loops?  You might want to consider the scope of your variables - do they need to be declared outside the loop?

Comment: ,No that's not my questions. That method has two parameter, one is ip address and second is timeout. So if the response is coming back under 5 millisecond, then its good. But if it is taking longer time means greater than 5 ms, then it will throw time out exceptions. So I am calculating the difference of time. So my question is why the program is entering in the if loop `if(difference> 5)` , it should have thrown the time out exception at previous place.

Comment: Are you saying that you are seeing some "Debug" print outs without a "Timeout Exception" printout?

Comment: Ah - I which case look at the variables, they are not being re-initialised in each loop, so I think you might be getting hangover from one loop to the next

Comment: I don't think so that can be the problem. Because everytime they are taking System.nanoTime for each particular query.

Comment: Actually reading again I'm not sure what the issue is you are trying to find - could you post the output from a run, and point out the bits that are not what you expect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9030/discussion-between-raihan-jamal-and-matt-harrison)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 'difference' to zero at the top of the loop, or in a final 'else' block. At present it is possible to reuse the previous value.

Comment: With the use of debugger, I saw that it is not taking any previous value. It can be because of catch block. It might be possible that response is coming back in under 5 ms. But it is printing in the catch block. So that's it is taking extra time. there and then I am calculating the difference after that?

Comment: @RaihanJamal it doesn't matter in the slightest what you saw in the debugger. Without this fix your code is wrong.

Comment: What you are saying I know. I already have difference 0 above the while loop. And where else should I put difference to zero.

Comment: @RaihanJamal I've already answered that question. You don't have a final 'else' on that condition, so it is possible for 'difference' not to be assigned at all inside the loop. Surely this is obvious?